# Use baseapi.h methods Teseract iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, tesseract

I setup Tesseract by adding the tessdata by reference, then adding the tesseract-ios and tesseract-ios-lib as groups.

This is the guide I followed. [Guide](http://lois.di-qual.net/blog/install-and-use-tesseract-on-ios-with-tesseract-ios/)

I imported `#import "Tesseract.h"` in my ViewController.m file and I can successfully use Tesseract but can't use the methods defined in baseapi.h Tesseract.mm imports baseapi.h as a side note.

```
Tesseract *tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc]init];

[tesseract setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"card.jpg"]];
[tesseract recognize];
char *utf8Text=tesseract->GetHOCRText(0);
```

I am getting the error of `"Tesseract" does not have a member named "GetHOCRText"`

How can I use the methods defined in baseapi.h while developing on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421472/ocr-tessearct-scanning-chunks-of-text-not-left-to-right-ios/21422515#21422515). In that answer i have mentioned how can you set rect which defined in baseapi.h with tesseract. Same way you can try for this too.

Go to Tesseract.mm file and add this code there.

```
- (NSString *)getHOCRText {
        char *boxtext = _tesseract->GetHOCRText(0);
        return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:boxtext];
}
```

Go to Tesseract.h file and define method :

```
- (NSString *)getHOCRText;
```

Then you can use that method to get HOCRText.

```
[tesseract getHOCRText];
```

Comment: Just have a look this code. Similarly you can setup each functions as a method yourself.

Comment: does it create correct html that includes correct padding between lines?